# How to force WGET command NOT to bring any Timestamps in the response?

Tags: http, curl, https, http-headers, wget

I want to take hash of a remote webpage at regular intervals, and then compare the current and previous hash to know if anything has changed.

For that I am using the **`wget`** command to retrieve data recursively.

My requirement is that I need to get a different hash only when some change has occurred in the contents of the web page viewed by the end users in their browser.

If I execute a simple wget command like

**`wget --recursive --page-requirements --convert-links URL/TO/WEBPAGE`**

the response will contain timestamps in the header, and I will get a different hash every time.

In `cURL` I can set an option to not get any headers in response, but I don't know how to enforce that in `wget`?

**So the question is that what do I do so that response to `wget` command does bring any headers?**

Answer (score 0):

Store the web page(s) in a file, and use that one to calculate your hash.

```
wget --recursive --page-requirements --convert-links -O /tmp/wget.txt URL/TO/WEBPAGE
md5sum /tmp/wget.txt
```

Comment: From the look of it, the web page stored in the `wget.txt` file will actually be the html text-string of the webpage, which will only include the textual path to the images added to the page and not the images themselves. But I need to get a different hash if the image changed, even if the path to he image (including the image name) remains the same. :-$

Comment: In that case, your original statement would have been sufficient.  The headers are not stored in the retrieved files.